# Aspect around methods annotated with @RabbitHandler

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

What I want is to have an aspect around all methods annotated with @RabbitHandler so that AssertionErrors won't kill the handler thread.

I just want to wrap them inside RuntimeExceptions and rethrow.

Motivation: there is additional error handling that I want to use which works well except for these AssertionErrors.

I could add a try-catch for AssertionErrors in each method but there are too many places and instead I was thinking of using aspects.

```
@Aspect
public class RabbitAssertionErrorHandlerAspect {

  @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler)")
  public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    try {
      return pjp.proceed();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

All nice and elegant but it doesn't get called. I assume this has something to do with the way these methods are discovered in the first place.

Any reasonable workarounds anyone sees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Spring AOP...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48324210Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48324210Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodInterceptor interceptor() {
        return i -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("here");
                return i.proceed();
            }
            catch (AssertionError e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public static BeanNameAutoProxyCreator proxyCreator() {
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator pc = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        pc.setBeanNames("foo");
        pc.setInterceptorNames("interceptor");
        return pc;
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static class Foo {

        @RabbitListener(queues = "one")
        public void listen(Object in) {
            System.out.println(in);
        }

    }

}
```

or, as Artem said, a custom error handler will work too.

Comment: In the end I've customised `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory` with an advice chain including such a `MethodInterceptor`. Namely
`factory.setAdviceChain(interceptor())`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `@RabbitListener` on the class with those `@RabbitHandler`s can be configured with:

```
/**
 * Set an {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerErrorHandler}
 * to invoke if the listener method throws an exception.
 * @return the error handler.
 * @since 2.0
 */
String errorHandler() default "";
```

So, consider to go the custom `RabbitListenerErrorHandler` way instead.

Comment: I already have an error handler but only Exceptions are caught. AssertionError is an Error and is thus not included but just falls through the cracks and kills the thread.